# Cloning form fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I am attempting to clone fields in a form using Jquery.

I'm trying to achieve the following in terms of display:

```
SELECT     SELECT     TEXT INPUT
RADIO      RADIO      RADIO  

Clone 1
SELECT     SELECT     TEXT INPUT
RADIO      RADIO      RADIO

Clone2
SELECT     SELECT     TEXT INPUT
RADIO      RADIO      RADIO


What I end up getting is:
RADIO   RADIO    RADIO 
RADIO   RADIO    RADIO 
RADIO   RADIO    RADIO 
SELECT     SELECT     TEXT INPUT
SELECT     SELECT     TEXT INPUT
SELECT     SELECT     TEXT INPUT
```

In my code below, I have used the .after function to follow the Select options, but it still displays it above

$('#condition' + num).after(newElem);
 // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
 $('#logical' + num1).after(newElem);

A demo is on Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/ATzBA/

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="5" border="0">
          <tbody><tr id="logical1" class="clonedInput1">
              <td class="first-column">&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="logicalOperator" default>
                AND    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="logicalOperator" >
                OR    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="logicalOperator" >
                NOT
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="condition1" class="clonedInput">
              <td class="first-column">Condition #2</td>
              <td><span style="float:left; padding-right: 10px;">
                <select id="firstname" name="firstname" class="standard_select" style="width:147px; background:#fff;">
                   <option>Blah Name</option>
                   <option>Blah list</option>
                   <option>Blah Type</option>
                   <option>Blah Id</option>
                   <option>Blah Name</option>

                </select>&nbsp;<select id="firstname" name="firstname" class="standard_select" style="width:147px;">
                  <option>Equals =</option>
                  <option>Not Equal &lt;&gt;</option>
                  <option>Greater &gt;</option>
                  <option>Less &lt;</option>
                  <option>Contains</option>
                  <option>In</option>
                  <option>Not In</option>
                </select>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="conValue" name="conValue" class="short_input" value="" style="width:147px;">
                </span>
                </td>
</tr>
<tr>
              <td class="first-column">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
<div>
                    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnDele" value="Del" />
                </div>    
                </td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
​`            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var num1     = $('.clonedInput1').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
                var newNum1  = new Number(num1 + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#condition' + num).clone().attr('id', 'condition' + newNum);
                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem1 = $('#logical' + num1).clone().attr('id', 'logical' + newNum1);

                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum1).attr('name', 'name' + newNum1);

                // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                $('#condition' + num).after(newElem);
                // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                $('#logical' + num1).after(newElem1);

                // enable the "remove" button
                $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','');

                // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum1 == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDele').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var num1 = $('.clonedInput1').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#condition' + num).remove();     // remove the last element
                $('#logical' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','disabled');
                if (num1-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','disabled');

​`
```

Comment: If you use div's instead of a table, your code would be cleaner and easier to manipulate. You could then group all related/initial elements within a div and just clone and append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newElem1 is inserted after the logicalxxx item, which is before the last inserted condition item. If you replace

```
           // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#condition' + num).after(newElem);
            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#logical' + num1).after(newElem1);
```

with

```
  $('#condition' + num).after(newElem).after(newElem1);
```

newelem1 is inserted directly after newelem and I think that gives the desired effect (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ATzBA/2/ )